# Is anyone familiar with thought-experiments in mathematics?

Tags: discussion

I have posed a series of thought-experiments in the main math stack. They may be considered philosophy, but I have only been a high-school/secondary-school teacher and for me it is a practical matter, not an abstruse or particularly sophisticated investigation. Thought-experiments are the only way I can consider making progress in the direction of thought I am exploring.

Is the main stack or this meta appropriate for this particular exploration of mathematics?

Comment: ah... I've just seen that the few reputation points I mustered from my initial query (winning me a massive 14 points) has bombed as a result of my series of thought-experiments (currently 1 and dropping fast)...

Comment: Reputation cannot go below 1.

Comment: The notion of "thought experiment" that I am familiar with does not match the queries you have posted. (To me, a 'thought experiment' describes discussions like Schrodinger's cat experiment or  Einstein's "weigh a photon" attempt). Asking "what is the verb in '2+3=5'?" or "where does the mental activity reside in '2+3=5'?" (which I confess reads like nonsense to me, but then I'm not a native speaker) do not conform to my notion of "thought experiment". What do you mean by "thought experiment"?

Comment: you are thinking of thought-experiment in physics, @ArturoMagidin, whereas i thought this was a place to examine mathematics... neither am i interested in philosophy -- too many words :)

Comment: @happyseaurchin: I am thinking of "thought-experiments" in the only way in which I am familiar. Your questions simply do not match that idea, and that is why I am asking what it is you consider a "mathematics thought experiment". Again: asking for "what is the verb in '2+3=5'?" does not seem like philosophy, mathematics, or "thought-experiments" to me, it sounds like linguistics and grammar. Asking about "where does the  mental activity reside" does not make sense to me at all (the obvious answer is "in my brain", but somehow, I suspect that's not the answer you are looking for...)

Comment: i don't think the question is based on "language"... i ask the question, and i get a variety of answers: most think it is centred around the "+", mostly because the suggestion of 3 objects and physically adding another 2 objects, as we learnt as children... some people think it is at the "=", and i think this indicates a different way of thinking that is not related to objects... though programmers often chose the "=" sign because it is operational, in that let x=x+1... but i am not particularly interested in programming either :)

Comment: @happyseaurchin: Equations are abbreviations for statements. There was a time when all of math was discussed "discursively"; equations are simply a way of writing that discourse in a compact, convenient, and useful way. You say "I get a variety of answers"; who are you asking? And do they understand your question? Because I for one am becoming bewildered as to just what it is you are driving at or searching for.

Comment: @happyseaurchin Also note that thought experiments are performed in one's head and are not psychological experiments.  They are different matters altogether.

Comment: On [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2423808#2423808), Bill the Lizard pointed to [this related meta.SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112053/) and asked if the mods could weigh in on that.

Comment: I have to say that I find the description a bit self-serving. I did not see any attempt at "explaining the methodology [he has] been using"... (unless that refers to the vague "I ask the question, I get a variety of answers").  Though I was wondering about the suspension myself somewhat.

Comment: @t.b. the main things I would say have already been well-said by Shog9 (over at Meta.SO) and Arturo (here). If the OP wants more specific clarifications, he should contact the Moderators either by e-mail or by responding to the private Moderation Message that Qiaochu sent him over the weekend.

Answer (score 8):

Meta is for discussion of topics related to the main site. A perusal of the questions posted here will quickly show you that Meta is *not* the place to engage in discussions *about* mathematics, whether they are technical, philosophical, semantical, pedagogical, or any other kind.

So, to answer your last question, Meta is not the appropriate venue for any exploration of mathematics; in particular, it is not the appropriate venue for the exploration of mathematics that you are attempting. See the very first of the [Frequently Asked Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), which is "What kind of questions can I ask here?"

As to the main site, the [parallel Frequently Asked Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) does not include the type of activity that you seem to want to engage in; to wit, *performing* your "thought experiments" here. (I am guessing that when you said "I ask the question and I get a variety of answers" that is your description of what a "mathematics thought-experiment is", so that you are looking to ask a question and get a variety of answers). Which seems to be the reason your questions have been down-voted and closed; they are off-topic. If you want to discuss *how* to ask questions that may be relevant to both your intention and the site, then meta is *definitely* the place to do it

Note, however, that a wide-ranging, open-ended discussion about mathematics is often not appropriate to either the main or the meta sites. If your intention is to engage in open-ended discussions about the 'new direction in mathematics' (as your [meta.SO question called it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112053/could-i-have-avoided-being-suspended-on-the-math-stack-for-7-days)) that you have opened up, then the main site is probably not the place to do it, either, because the main site is not a Discussion forum.